# Output file formatting and rearrangement

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python scripting and I hope somebody can help and give some advice on how to rearrange the order of contents in a text file.

Let's say I have:

```
A, X1, Y1, Z1
B, X2, Y2, Z2
C, X3, Y3, Z3
```

I have to change the order to become like this:

```
A, X1
A, Y1
A, Z1
B, X2
B, Y2
B, Z2
......
```

Can someone enlighten me on how to create a script to do this? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Best,
SIM

Comment: In favor of a better understanding, you should first try to solve such problems yourself (and include your attempt into the question). This place is intended to help you to solve problems, not to solve all of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().split(', ')  #split the line at ', '
        for item in line[1:]:    #iterate over slice of the list returned in the previous step
            print line[0], item  #print the first item, and the item from the loop.
```

**Output:**

```
A X1
A Y1
A Z1
B X2
B Y2
B Z2
C X3
C Y3
C Z3
```

**Explanation:**

```
>>> s = 'A, X1, Y1, Z1\n'
```

Here we first strip trailing white-spaces first and then split the line at `', '`. This step returns a list.

```
>>> lis = s.rstrip().split(', ')
>>> lis
['A', 'X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']
```

Using slicing we can get all the items starting from second:

```
>>> lis[1:]
['X1', 'Y1', 'Z1']
```

Now, we can iterate over this sliced list and print `lis[0]` and the item fetched during loop.